# How BusinessEntityContact is mapped with BusinessEntity, Contact and Person in AdventureWorks2008R2 database

Tags: sql-server-2008, adventureworks

How BusinessEntityContact is mapped with BusinessEntity, Contact and Person in AdventureWorks2008R2 database

I had a brainstorming on this to get how it is related. I queried BusinessEntityContact with Store, Person, Customer and I didn't understood what is going on..

[image]

This database is AdventureWorks2008R2 for Sql Server2008 R2

Comment: http://www.elsasoft.org/samples/ReportServer_adventureworks/SqlServer.SPRING.KATMAI.AdventureWorks2008/table_PersonBusinessEntityContact.htm